# ReactNative: AsyncStorage not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

Hello I am trying to impliment a login and the most of the logic is inside action creator but for some react my code doesn't execute after

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('adminFlag', adminFlag);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);`
```

the console.log(data) is working before this statement...I have no idea why this is happening

```
export const verifyPassword = (
    adminFlag,
    password,
    navigate
) => async dispatch => {
    loadingStatus(dispatch, true);

    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(
            "myurl with response success--lajja--token",
            {
                admin: adminFlag,
                job: "verifyPassword",
                password
            }
        );

        if (data.includes("--lajja--")) {
            //spliting the token and the response
            const destructuredData = data.trim().split("--lajja--");
            const response = destructuredData[0];
            const token = destructuredData[1];

            console.log(data);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("adminFlag", adminFlag);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", token);
            navigate();
            loadingStatus(dispatch, false);
        }
        loadingStatus(dispatch, false);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        loadingStatus(dispatch, false);
    }
};
```

the lines after console.log(data) are not working...

Comment: have you try log adminFlag and token ? is it null ? 
try remove await.. just use AsyncStorage.setItem('adminFlag', adminFlag)

Comment: AsyncStorage.setItem returns a promise. It looks that this promise is never resolved for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happened to me as well as to some people on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16905) issue. This seems to happen on Android devices (only during debug) that are running some background activities as specified [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16905#issuecomment-352895477) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/16905#issue-275658770). The pull request provided by [@github/jsdario](https://github.com/jsdario) to fix that issue seems to have not passed the CI though. I guess for now we have to debug... Without the debugger attached.